# CSS selector for multiple ids in one line (like [id="abc-1 - abc-10"]:checked + label)

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to do

```
[id="abc-1"]:checked + label,
[id="abc-2"]:checked + label,
[id="abc-3"]:checked + label,
[id="abc-4"]:checked + label,
[id="abc-5"]:checked + label,

...
```

in one line for multiple id's? Like

```
[id="abc-1 - abc-10"]:checked + label
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so you can do

```
[id^="abc-"]
```

which basically selects all elements which have an **id** attribute starting with **abc-**